# Node.js cuts off files when serving over HTTPS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to serve some JavaScript files with Node.js and for whatever reason the files are being cut off in the middle of the transmission. The code:

```
httpsServer = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    if (path[path.length - 1] == '/') {
            path += 'index.html';
    }

    fs.readFile(root + path, function(err, data){
            if (err) return send404(res);

            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': getMimeType(getExtension(path)),
                'Content-Length': data.length});
            res.end(data);

    });
}),

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(settings.PRIVATE_KEY).toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(settings.CERTIFICATE).toString();

var credentials = crypto.createCredentials({key: privateKey, cert: certificate});
httpsServer.setSecure(credentials);
httpsServer.listen(settings.HTTPS_PORT);
```

The files http://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/raw/master/socket.io.js and http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js. The first one is cut off at exactly 32KB and the second at exactly 16KB. This does not happen over HTTP, only HTTPS and only over a network (e.g.: not from localhost).

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of `Content-Length: data.length` you should use `Content-Length: Buffer.byteLength(data, 'utf8')` where `Buffer`is a global object (node 0.3.x) or `var Buffer = require('buffer')` in node 0.2.x which will save you a lot of hassle and might fix your problem with truncated answers too.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Well, this, actually: Buffer.byteLength(data, 'utf8'). Notice that "語語語".length == 3 while  Buffer.byteLength("語語語", 'utf8') == 9, the correct answer in this case.

Comment: Thanks Phil, oversaw that one!

Answer (score 1):

I have just seen this too.  Same setup - HTTPS, latest node from the git repo.

One large file  (170k) never properly completing sending. I tried to switch from async to synch but it made no difference.  Only thing that fixed it so far was making the file smaller.  It was a big floppy jpg so it was easy to do.  Problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a disconnect between the default encoding for readFile and res.end().  readFile just loads the raw data if you do not specify an encoding whereas end() defaults to utf8.  I'm not 100% sure but the raw data from the file could return a shorter length than the utf8 encoded string that end emits.

I tried recreating your error and failed so it might be you need to upgrade your version of node. I'm using the latest code from github.

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be solved in the newest version of Node.js. Can you test it out on [v0.4.2](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/v0.4.2)?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use built-in HTTPS server?
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/https.html