# Truncation when streaming large data from pipe in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to stream an arbitrarily large amount of data over HTTP from a subprocess using node. My full code is [here](https://github.com/conveyal/vanilla-extract/blob/master/vexserver.js), and the salient bit is:

```
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=osm_export_' +
      ((north + south) / 2) + '_' + ((east + west) / 2) + '.pbf'
    });

  // run vex
  var proc = spawn(cmd, [dbname, south, west, north, east, '-']);

  // stream chunks
  proc.stdout.pipe(res);
```

After approximately 40 MB (anywhere between 40,000,000 and 42,000,000 bytes) the stream is interrupted and the request never completes. I can't set a `Content-Length` header because I don't know how much data the command will produce until it is done I'm wondering if this is a buffer underrun; the command in question is extracting data from a database and writing a stream, which could possibly be slower than the connection between my computer and my server. I suspect this because I replaced the code with this:

```
var http = require('http');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'});

  var proc = spawn('head', ['-c', '500000000', '/dev/zero']);

  proc.stdout.pipe(res);
}).listen(8181, '127.0.0.1');
```

which streams 500MB of null data, and it worked fine. Is there some sort of timeout, etc. that I need to set?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, found the issue. This may or may not be useful to others. I was not doing anything with the process `stderr` stream, and the backend process writes a lot of status information to stderr. A buffer inside node somewhere was getting filled up and then it was crashing. Changing the process creation line to

```
  var proc = spawn(cmd, [dbname, south, west, north, east, '-'], {stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'ignore']});
```

solved the problem. Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up the HTTP header `Content-Length` and set its value to the size of the data you use in the response.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, this is sequentially reading a file and filtering it, so I don't know the content-length beforehand; I should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: I don't know how to help, this is the only possible solution I found, and I found it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905473/node-js-cuts-off-files-when-serving-over-https?rq=1 . Bye